# What methods are available to assign a TPL to a specific url for Drupal 7 theming?

Tags: 7, theming

Currently I have a custom javascript libary that is being loaded on all pages of the site as i hardcoded it into the **html.tpl.php** file. I konw you can target specific nodes or node types via the tpl filename format, but what if I wanted more control of where this tpl is activated? Is there some type of regex formating that I can use for html.tpl.php?

What I want to be able to do is load my custom js library on all pages **except** for a specific content type and a few views urls. How can this be done the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset the JS or CSS assets on page build with either hook page build or hook page process and drupal add js.

Alternatively you can use hook theme to define custom tpl files on custom business logic (such as url paths).

Im on my phone, unable to gives more info or examples until at pc.

Comment: i just made a conditional js snippet to detect the node type via the body classes. its one method, whats ur opinion on that compared to yours? thx

Comment: A method using the drupal api and php does not require JS on the client system.

Comment: i guess its 2 approaches then. the backend approach of doing it through the api or just do it via the frontend using js making the client do the work. performance wouldnt be an issue since its just a small addition.